# Check whether a string is a valid date or not in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I am having an xml document in which there are some date nodes and I am trying to get their values if the values are valid dates otherwise empty string.

**XML:**

```
<root>
  <START_DATE><![CDATA[03/05/2015]]></START_DATE>
  <START_DATE><![CDATA[05/05/2015]]></START_DATE>
  <START_DATE><![CDATA[Online]]></START_DATE>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="START_DATE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="if(string(normalize-space(.)) castable as xs:date) then normalize-space(.) else ''"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Output:**

```
,,,
```

**Expected:**

```
03/05/2015,05/05/2015,,
```

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Your stylesheet declares version 1.0, but it will only work with an XSLT 2.0 processor. Initially you have tagged this question `Xalan`, now you have removed this tag. Please clarify.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The processor is `Xalan` and I have tagged it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> get their values if the values are valid dates otherwise empty string

Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor. XSLT 1.0 has no concept of "date", so you will have to perform the validation yourself. The exact method depends on what exactly does "valid date" mean in this context.

If it's sufficient to ensure that the string purporting to be a date is **formatted** as a date (i.e. has exactly this pattern "##/##/####"), then the test can be quite simple:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(., '123456789', '000000000') = '00/00/0000'">
    <!-- result if valid -->
</xsl:if>
```

If you also need to test whether the purported date is a valid date in the Gregorian calendar (i.e. not "13/13/2015", for example), then it gets much more complicated.

---

***A note about XSLT 2.0:***

In XSLT 2.0, you can use `castable as xs:date` to test if a date is valid. However, even a valid date formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` will not pass this test. You must convert these strings to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format first.

Comment: In 2.0 I was validating like this: `<xsl:value-of select="if(string(replace(normalize-space(.), '([0-9]{2})\D([0-9]{2})\D([0-9]{4})', '$3-$1-$2')) castable as xs:date) then normalize-space(.) else ''"></xsl:value-of>`

Comment: So why did you remove this from your post?

Comment: As, it is 2.0 solution. But I want some solution in 1.0 if possible.

Comment: I meant why did you remove the part where you rearrange the string from your XSLT 2.0 code? The solution for XSLT 1.0 is in my answer above.

Comment: I was just checking. But I need that part too.  Thanks it worked :)